# Handle URL scheme react-native and Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I would like to handle custom URL scheme in my react-native application. Thus I first added an eventListener in my JS code inside my root component like that :

```
componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

handleOpenURL = event => {
    console.log('event', event);
};
```

In my Xcode application, I added a custom URL scheme "com.myScheme".

My problem has appeared when I tried to add the function in my AppDelegate.swift to handle deep linking.

Here's my function :

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print(url)
    return true
}
```

It seems that return true is not enough to trigger my listener inside my application ...

I know there's an Objective-C method in the react-native documentation :

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

But I would like to deal only with Swift for my project in order to improve my skills in this language. The problem is I can't find any example of this function implemented using Swift.

That's why I'm asking some help to implement this method and then trigger my event inside my RN application.

Thank you for your understanding :)

Comment: how you import RCTLinkingManager in swift ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding your AppDelegate method, the swift version should be :

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exaclty what I was looking for ! It works like a charm ;)

Comment: how to import `RCTLinkingManager` in swift

Comment: Just by importing React

Comment: @Hurobaki you mean this import React ? can you share your swift file code here ?

Comment: I mean you should already have React package imported `import React` at your top file. And don’t forget your import inside your Bridging-Header.h `#import « React/RCTLinkingManager.h ».

Comment: Thanks I gotcha now :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Ro22e0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6035317/ro22e0) worked great for me.  My app supports universal links too, so I also needed a swift equivalent for the following function provided in the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/linking):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

I'm not too comfortable with Swift, but I was eventually able to get a working solution by trial and error:

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
    restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void
) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
}
```